# CSS corner ribbon without rotate

Tags: css

There many tutorials to make **corner ribbon**, and of all tutorial using **transform/rotate 45 deg**. It makes content inside div (font) also rotate. I don't want it. I want to make like below picture, **font/symbol still stand-up**.  [image: ribbon]

I try to make a **triangle background**, but I can't make like what I want. 
[image: triangle]

Comment: can you post your code? are you using `:before` to make the corner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Dedi Ananto :  Please take note of the following code:

```
<div class="arrow-right"></div>

.arrow-right {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
    border-left: 60px solid red;
}
```

Hope this Helps..

Regards,
Karan